# Getting a JSON file using flutterfire stack

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase's realtime database store JSON files with google map marker locations. I have been using the [google maps API](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/google-maps-in-flutter/blob/master/step-6/lib/src/locations.dart). However, I cannot figure out how to get the json from realtime database to the flutter code, specifically in this section:

```
Future<Locations> getGoogleOffices() async {
  return Locations.fromJson(
    json.decode(
      // get json file
  );
}
```

Previously I was referencing the JSON file locally to bug fix the app. I would greatly appreciate any help and apologies as I am quite new to flutter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have well setup the `Fireabse` application instance:

```
final FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(); // somewhere in your `main` starter method
```

### Firestore Database

You can query a *Firestore* collection data as follows:

```
Future<Locations> getGoogleOffices() async {
  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('locations').doc('documentId').get();
  return Locations.fromJson(
    json.decode(
      documentSnapshot.data()
  );
}
```

### EDIT: Firebase Realtime Database

In order to access data from *Fireabse Realtime Database* instead of *Firestore*, you can attempt something as follows:

```
Future<Locations> getGoogleOffices() async {
  final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase(app: firebaseApp).reference();
  final DataSnapshot data = await db.child('locations').get();
  return Locations.fromJson(
    json.decode(
      data!.value
  );
}
```

The `DatabaseReference#get` API call will feed a reference to the most up-to-date result for this query.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you help, how would I do this query for a firebase's realtime database instead? I cannot find this equivalent for the realtime database.

Comment: Ive done it by 
  `DataSnapshot snap = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('locations').once();`
This causes another error _NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<Object?>' has no instance method 'call'_ but I believe this to be caused by another issue.

Comment: Sorry @vernal123 for not pointing the extra details for *Firebase Realtime Database*. I added the API reference to have a complete overview.